# How to format dotProject phone number fields in a view

Tags: php, formatting, phone-number, dotproject

I'm currently using dotProject Version 2.1.3 for our company and I would like a little help with the phone number format in the view company view.  Currently it allows you to place and group of numbers in any format.  So I can type (619)555-1234 ext-123 and it will display that way.  My problem is that I don't want the number to be stored in the database that way.  I only want the database to store just the numbers as one whole number.

So what I'm working with is the following code.  How to change this php page code to display the phone numbers in a visually pleasing format like from this 55512312125512 to this (555)123-1212 ext:5512?
[what the fields currently look like](http://www.it911now.com/images/dotproject_phone_number.jpg)

```
<tr>
        <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $AppUI->_('
        '); ?>:</td>
        <td class="hilite"><?php echo @$obj->company_phone1; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Phone'); ?>2:</td>
        <td class="hilite"><?php echo @$obj->company_phone2; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Fax'); ?>:</td>
        <td class="hilite"><?php echo @$obj->company_fax; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

for these 3 phone number fields to display in the format (555)123-4567 ext-any number of digits and still store in the database as continuous number like 555123456?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Avoid using error suppression `@` instead do something like `<?php echo (isset($obj) && is_object($obj)) ? $obj->company_phone1 : ''; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for dotProject Version 2.1.3 on the modules/companies/view.php page:

```
<tr> <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"> <?php echo $AppUI->_('Phone'); ?>: </td> <td class="hilite"> <?php $data = @$obj->company_phone1; if(preg_match( '/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d*)$/', $data, $matches )) { if($matches[4] != '') $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3] . ' ext.' . $matches[4]; else $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3]; echo $result; } ?> </td> </tr> </code>
```

This was gratefully provided by [(alex-sorin-dachin)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457108/alex-sorin-dachin)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $AppUI->_('Phone');

if(preg_match( '/^\+\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $data,  $matches )) {
    $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3];
    echo $result;
}
```

This should work

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. Now where do I place it or am I supposed to replace that block of code that I provided? Sorry that I'm such a NOOB on this.

Comment: well, firstly, replace echo @$obj->company_phone1; with the code I provided to you, but with the $data variable changed to @$obj->company_phone1. And then, replace echo @$obj->company_phone2; with the same code, but with the $data variable changed to @$obj->company_phone2.

Comment: [code]<tr>
   <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Phone'); ?>:</td> 
   <td class="hilite"><?php echo $data = @$obj->company_phone1;  if(preg_match( '/^\+\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $data,  $matches )) {     $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3];     echo $result; } ?></td>
  </tr> [code]

Comment: The phone 1 still shows the original number and the corrected number that your code fix.  The code did not work however on the Phone 2 and all the code is the same, with a 2 at the end.  Any suggestions?

Comment: delete the first echo before the $data variable. The code should be:

Comment: <tr> <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Phone'); ?>:</td> <td class="hilite"><?php $data = @$obj->company_phone1; if(preg_match( '/^\+\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $data, $matches )) { $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3]; echo $result; } ?></td> </tr>

Comment: Fantastic!! it worked.  The last thing about it is that it only works if it number has the format +17605555555. If I remove the + the phone number disappears in the view. So I removed +\ and this worked.  Last thing is that there are numbers that have numbers at the end for extensions. Those companies numbers are completely blank.  How do I remove the 1 and place ext.### and the end? So in the database it would be 76055555559999 but I would like it to display (760)555-5555 ext.9999? or any length of extension numbers.

Comment: Try this: <tr> <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Phone'); ?>:</td> <td class="hilite"><?php $data = @$obj->company_phone1; if(preg_match( '/^\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d+)$/', $data, $matches )) { $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3] . ' ext.' . $matches[4]; echo $result; } ?></td> </tr>

Comment: It works great. The code you provided above however pushed everything to the left, not showing the first digit.  What I had to do was add {0} after the first d and presto.   Works just like we wanted. Thanks for everything, and I learned just a little bit.  I was wondering if this change was correct?   I was looking over the code and noticed that you have the same number of matches (4) as d's but I don't.   Is this correct or ok? This does allow me to put an unlimited amount of numbers and display the data correctly.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that the if the phone number does not have an ext. the number is not displayed.  How do I fix this? Here is the code I used.    <tr> <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Phone'); ?>:</td> <td class="hilite"><?php $data = @$obj->company_phone1; if(preg_match( '/^\d{0}(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d+)$/', $data, $matches )) { $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3] . ' ext.' . $matches[4]; echo $result; } ?></td> </tr>

Comment: This works: <tr> <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
 <?php echo $AppUI->_('Phone'); ?>:
</td> <td class="hilite">

<?php $data = @$obj->company_phone1; 
if(preg_match( '/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d*)$/', $data, $matches )) { 
 if($matches[4] != '')
  $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3] . ' ext.' . $matches[4]; 
 else
  $result = '(' . $matches[1] . ')' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3]; 

 echo $result; 
} ?>

</td> </tr>

Comment: You don't have to put d{0} because it's useless. This matches 0 digits.

Comment: Great your the best. This is the answer.  Are you looking for work? :)

Comment: Former dotproject contrib, current web2project lead developer here..  you should be careful about stripping out the non-numeric characters - like +, (, ), -, and . - because there are numerous number display formats depending on country. The official spec is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

Comment: Thank you for the warning.  The only reason that they are there in the first place was that or phone routing system looks at the phone number column to verify the customer and process the call to technical support in this case.  Asterisk processed the entire caller id which included the +1 and the 10 digit number. This makes the CRM that we use hard to read, and we plan on installing the capability to dial out of this CRM in the future. Have currently working on stripping out the +1 in the Asterisk system right now so that I can keep track of the calls also in this CRM.

Comment: Any and all of your help that you can provide is greatly appreciated. Also CaseySoftware you look pretty young for 92.

Comment: I'm not sure is this bumping or not, but will this code work on the input page in this CRM? <tr>
  <td align="right"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Phone'); ?> 1:</td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" class="text" name="company_phone1" value="<?php 
echo dPformSafe(@$obj->company_phone1); ?>" maxlength="30" />
  </td>
 </tr>